# PayPal C# SDK Endpoint

Tags: c#, paypal

I'm looking for a way to set the PayPal SOAP API endpoint in the code rather than specifying it in the web.config or app.config.  I need to read & use the endpoint from an environment-specific configuration that is not the web.config/app.config.

Is this possible?  I've read some of the code for the SDK on their github repo and it does not appear possible but I'm hoping I missed something.

I'm using the PayPal Merchant SDK for .Net, ver 2.1.96.0.

Comment: Am I the only one INFURIATED by PayPal's ridiculous statement that  "Self-documented classes that describe the APIs" passes for documentation??? https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Comment: apparently they've fixed this issue in the main codebase. I'm not sure exactly how since I have no need to update it right now but if you're new to this issue you'll want to check the latest merchant SDK first

Answer (score 6):

I needed to be able to specify all important settings outside of the .config file. I'm lazy so here's how I did it:

```
paypalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
paypalConfig.Add("apiUsername", "xxxxx");
paypalConfig.Add("apiPassword", "xxxxx");
paypalConfig.Add("apiSignature", "xxxxx");
==>paypalConfig.Add("mode","live|sandbox");
```

And then you need to call your method by specifying again the credentials (haven't investigated much why this is necessary):

```
var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(paypalConfig);
var doCaptureResponse = service.DoCapture(amount, new SignatureCredential(paypalConfig["apiUsername"], paypalConfig["apiPassword"], paypalConfig["apiSignature"]));
```

Comment: This seems to be the proposed way by paypal to provide the config data via code - From Paypal @knakai - you can actually use the SDK now without the config section - you just need to initialize it as an instance rather than using it statically. This is a constructor from the newer version (make sure you're up to date):

public PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Dictionary<string, object> config);
You build the dictionary to pass into the constructor, so it can come from a database or external config.

Comment: this is not lazy at all and this should be the accepted answer now! this is basically what should have been possible all along. note: this constructor was added around the time you added your answer (I'm not sure the exact version). this happened somewhere between versions 2.1.96 and 2.5.103 but when I wrote my crazy long involved answer this constructor didn't exist

Answer (score 4):

**Answer 2: BUT If you're fine with editing PayPal's code this will work fine...**

**(PayPal: if you're reading this PLEASE implement this feature!!)**

---

**EDIT: THIS IS NO LONGER NECESSARY - SEE ANSWER BY Simon Labrecque**

---

So after spending HOURS on this and having written my application around the expectation that I could switch endpoint between live and sandbox (just like I used to when directly calling the SOAP service) I decided to just go and dig into the source more and figure it out.

Here's the changes I made to get it to work.

Assumptions:

- You must be using the [new PayPal SDK for C#](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index).
- It is easiest to install with nuGet package manager : Install both [Core](http://nuget.org/packages/PayPalCoreSDK/) and [Merchant](http://nuget.org/packages/PayPalMerchantSDK/)

Steps:

- You will be editing PayPal's source code and compiling locally - but only 2 files:
- Blank out the `endpoint` in web.config under `<paypal>`. Recommended safety precaution!
- Download source for `PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.cs` [from GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/PayPalMerchantSDK/PayPalAPIInterfaceService/PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.cs) (Merchant SDK)
- Download source for `DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler.cs` [from GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler.cs) (Core SDK)
- You probably want to take a minute to make sure the version is the same as your nuGet package.
- Make a copy of both of these in your project in a folder `PayPalMerchantSDK` or something like that
- I'd recommend renaming both files to avoid confusion and conflict with the NuGet versions. I got frustrated and just called them `SimonsPayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService` and `SimonsSOAPAPICallHandler` - but call them whatever you want.

### Changes to SimonsSOAPAPICallHandler.cs

Change the constructor to add a boolean `useSandbox`:

Note: It must be the first parameter because we're going to do some search and replace magic soon.

```
    public SimonsSOAPAPICallHandler(bool useSandbox, string rawPayLoad, string attributesNamespace,
        string headerString)
        : base()
    {
        this.rawPayLoad = rawPayLoad;
        this.nmespceAttributes = attributesNamespace;
        this.headElement = headerString;

        // you can get these from config if you wish but I doubt they'll ever change
        this.endpoint = useSandbox ? "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0" : "https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0";
    }
```

Change `GetEndPoint()`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the endpoint for the API call
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetEndPoint()
    {
        return this.endpoint;
    }
```

Add a corresponding member:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Endpoint
    /// </summary>
    private string endpoint;
```

### Changes to SimonsPayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.cs

Modify the constructor to add a `useSandbox` parameter

```
public SimonsPayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(bool useSandbox) 
{ 
    this.useSandbox = useSandbox; 
}
```

Add a corresponding member

```
    private bool useSandbox;
```

Do two search and replaces on this file. You'll have about 100 replacements for each

- Replace `new DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler(` with `new SimonsSOAPAPICallHandler(useSandbox,`
- Replace `DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler defaultHandler` with `var defaultHandler`

What you just did was added `useSandbox` as a parameter to the constructor of `SimonsSOAPAPICallHandler` (which thankfully implements `IAPICallPreHandler`) and you'll end up with this for each method:

```
 public DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType DoExpressCheckoutPayment(DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq doExpressCheckoutPaymentReq, string apiUserName)
{
    IAPICallPreHandler apiCallPreHandler = null;
    string portName = "PayPalAPIAA";
    setStandardParams(doExpressCheckoutPaymentReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest);
    var defaultHandler = new SimonsSOAPAPICallHandler(useSandbox, doExpressCheckoutPaymentReq.ToXMLString(null, "DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq"), null, null);
    apiCallPreHandler = new MerchantAPICallPreHandler(defaultHandler, apiUserName, getAccessToken(), getAccessTokenSecret());
    ((MerchantAPICallPreHandler) apiCallPreHandler).SDKName = SDKName;
    ((MerchantAPICallPreHandler) apiCallPreHandler).SDKVersion = SDKVersion;
    ((MerchantAPICallPreHandler) apiCallPreHandler).PortName = portName;
    string response = Call(apiCallPreHandler);
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(response);
    XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponse']");
    return new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType(xmlNode);

}
```

---

That's it!

Now when you call a method you can say ...

```
bool useSandbox = true; // or false
var service = new SimonsPayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(useSandbox);
```

Then call the method as normal

```
caller.DoExpressCheckoutPayment(pp_request, config.AccountName);
```

Note: It will still look for the account name in your config to find the corresponding keys. Obviously **be careful updating to a later version of the Merchant SDK cos you'll have to do this all over again**.

I hope someone finds this useful :-)

Comment: I'm impressed!  I wouldn't have had the patience to track this down and try and figure out how to modify their code to make this work.  That being said, I'm even more convinced now that their "API" is just a repackaging of their WSDL, and I highly suggest just using the web service with the hard-coded binding from my answer.  I can't think of any reason to prefer the packaged "API" over that.

Comment: I just got to the point of no return with this one and the way everything is organized makes it look at first glance like it *must* be possible. I'd already invested time in my own code assuming it was possible so one way or the other I needed to make it work. In a previous version of my app I had used the WSDL and it wasn't a problem I just assumed the API was the way to go

Comment: And the good news is that one of the developers already contacted me back and told me they agreed this was a useful feature and they'll implement it in the next version : https://github.com/paypal/SDKs/issues/43

Comment: apparently they've fixed this issue in the main codebase. I'm not sure exactly how since I have no need to update it right now but if you're new to this issue you'll want to check there first

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely doable, but you have to hard-code the values by creating the bindings as objects.  This is what I've worked out for my own project:

```
protected static PayPalAPIInterface GetService()
{
    return new PayPalAPIInterfaceClient(new BasicHttpBinding()
            {
                SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 200000,
                Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
                {
                    Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
                    Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
                                    {
                                        ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None,
                                        ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None,
                                    },
                    Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity()
                                {
                                    ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate,
                                }
                }
            },
            new EndpointAddress(@"https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/")
        ).ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
}
```

There's more parameters you can set - in theory, everything in the `.config` file can be reproduced here.  This works for me, though, so I didn't take it any further.

It's also worth noting that this enables you to put the PayPal calls into a library and *not* have to copy the binding into the config file of the project that includes that library, which was why I developed it in the first place.

---

Edit:  Here's the basic definition of `PayPalAPIInterfaceClient` - no guarantees that it will actually be sufficient for use.

```
public partial class PayPalAPIInterfaceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService>
{
    public PayPalAPIInterfaceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding,
                                    System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) 
           : base(binding, remoteAddress) { }
}
```

You'd also modify the earlier code to have a return type of `PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService` instead.

Comment: Where would I find PayPalAPIInterfaceClient?  I don't see it in the Merchant or Core SDK...?

Comment: @wessiyad - It's automatically generated by creating a new Service Reference for  `https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl`.

Comment: I'm using the SDK, so I'm looking for a way to do it through that.

Comment: @wessiyad - See if what I just added helps.

Comment: Get an InvalidOperationException - "The type argument passed to the generic ChannelFactory class must be an interface type."  Looks like since PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService is not an interface this wont work...

Comment: @wessiyad - I'm not entirely surprised by that.  In the code I was copying from, it had an interface, but I didn't want to copy any more than I had to so I stripped it out.  I can post more of it, but at some point it's going to just *be* the webservice.  Since my impression was that the API, at it's core, just communicated with the webservice, have you considered switching?

Comment: I've thought about it, but I have a work around for it for now.  If possible I'd still like to be able to set the endpoint without the workaround, but it isn't a big enough deal for me to redo something that is already there.

Comment: @wessiyad what was your workaround? I figured it out if you're ok changing the source code of 2 files

Comment: Why has this not got more votes?  The only other answers I found were altering the PayPal SDK code... this is simple, tidy, and works great. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** I agree - not possible out of the box.

It really doesn't seem to be possible without compiling the code yourself and changing quite a lot. Here's the current [code from GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet%2a) for `PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService` which is actually generated - probably using a T4 template. This is a massive 2489 line file with code like this for every API method.

The key thing here is `IAPICallPreHandler`. You'll see it's set to null and then initialized to an instance of `MerchantAPICallPreHandler`. There's no way to pass it in.

```
    public SetExpressCheckoutResponseType SetExpressCheckout(SetExpressCheckoutReq setExpressCheckoutReq, ICredential credential)
    {
        IAPICallPreHandler apiCallPreHandler = null;
        string portName = "PayPalAPIAA";
        setStandardParams(setExpressCheckoutReq.SetExpressCheckoutRequest);
        DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler(setExpressCheckoutReq.ToXMLString(null, "SetExpressCheckoutReq"), null, null);
        apiCallPreHandler = new MerchantAPICallPreHandler(defaultHandler, credential);
        ((MerchantAPICallPreHandler) apiCallPreHandler).SDKName = SDKName;
        ((MerchantAPICallPreHandler) apiCallPreHandler).SDKVersion = SDKVersion;
        ((MerchantAPICallPreHandler) apiCallPreHandler).PortName = portName;
        string response = Call(apiCallPreHandler);
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(response);
        XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='SetExpressCheckoutResponse']");
        return new SetExpressCheckoutResponseType(xmlNode);

    }
```

Now let's look at the interface :

```
public interface IAPICallPreHandler
{
    ICredential GetCredential();
    string GetEndPoint();
    Dictionary<string, string> GetHeaderMap();
    string GetPayLoad();
}
```

Doh! Doesn't `GetEndPoint()` look kinda like what we'd want to override.

Delving deeper into the code - the instance of `GetEndPoint()` that is ultimately called is this one in `DefaultSOAPAPICallHandler` - which as you can see goes straight to the `ConfigManager`.

```
    public string GetEndPoint() 
    {
        return ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperty(BaseConstants.END_POINT);
}
```

`ConfigManager` just goes straight to `web.config` or `app.config`

```
  config = (SDKConfigHandler)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("paypal");
```

There's no hooks or anything else to change the endpoint unfortunately.

I've considered compiling it locally and fixing it, but I'd rather lose the ability to change the endpoint in code than lose the ability to one-click update the whole package.